# Bash vs. Dash behavior with the command `echo -ne "hello\n"`

Tags: bash, dash-shell

I got different behaviors with the same command `echo -ne "hello\n"` with bash and with dash. See below :

```
$ bash -c 'echo -ne "hello\n"'
hello
$ dash -c 'echo -ne "hello\n"'
-ne hello
```

Why is that ? I don't understand at all…

My system :

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Comment: dash is properly conforming with the POSIX standard for how `echo` is supposed to behave; bash ignores that standard (one of the few places where, rather than extending undefined behavior, it's outright noncompliant).

Comment: Incidentally, if you `export POSIXLY_CORRECT=1`, and then use GNU's `/bin/echo`, you'll see it behave the same way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `bash` did not ignore, it only did not chose that behavior by default.

Comment: @cuonglm, fair enough. Even so, I continue to hold that Chet erred badly in choosing noncompliant-by-default behavior (though it's certainly far too late to fix).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The POSIX specification for `echo` doesn't support any arguments. See it [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

And while the spec mentions `-n` it does so to say that it is *not* an option and is either an implementation defined case or to be treated as a string.

So `dash` is doing exactly that.

`bash`, on the other hand, has non-conforming behavior in a number of ways.

This is why the use of `echo` is generally discouraged in favor of the using `printf` which has a much better specification and much better portable behavior.

Comment: You can make bash `echo` became conformant, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33785401/2218718).

Comment: Does that mean that `echo` is not a program but a native command of the shell ?

Comment: @Quentin: You often have `echo` builtin in your shell, and also external program `/bin/echo`.

Comment: @Quentin, if the external `/bin/echo` program were being used, you wouldn't have seen it change behavior based on the active shell. Shells not including `echo` as a builtin have been pretty much unheard of for decades, now.

Comment: OK it really makes sense, I thought it was an external program so I could not understand why the behavior would be different from one shell to another

Answer (score 2):

While `echo` implementation in `bash` is not POSIX and Unix conformed by default, you can alter its behavior at run time or compile time.

At run time, with `xpg_echo` and in POSIX mode, `bash` `echo` became conformant:

```
$ env BASHOPTS=xpg_echo SHELLOPTS=posix bash -c 'echo -ne "hello\n"'
-ne hello
```

or:

```
$ env BASHOPTS=xpg_echo POSIXLY_CORRECT= bash -c 'echo -ne "hello\n"'
-ne hello
```

At compile time, you can pass `--enable-xpg-echo-default` and `--enable-strict-posix-default` options to `configure` script.

Answer (score 0):

It's been stated in a previous answer that it's because dash doesn't use/understand the -n argument for echo, but this is not true.

Dash uses the -n argument to not print out a newline. But the example uses -ne.
The following are all from dash version 0.5.12-2 in Debian:

```
$ echo -n string
string$
$ echo -n -e string
-e string$
$ echo -ne string
-ne string
$
```

As you can see:

In "echo -n string", it prints string with no newline.

In "echo -n -e string", it prints no newline because -n is an allowed argument that dash recognizes, and then it treats -e as a string because it's not a valid argument according to POSIX.

In "echo -ne string", it treats -ne as a string because it's not a valid argument according to POSIX (because of the "e" part).